# Conditional condition not working as expected

Tags: groovy, spock

I noticed a weird behavior in how a condition in the `then` block gets evaluated. The condition should be evaluated after executing the `when` block, but in one specific case, it is getting executed before and so failing. I am able to reproduce the behavior with the below simple specification:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class ConditionalCondition extends Specification {
    def 'non-working condition check'() {
        given:
            def result = 0

        when:
            System.out.println("----- before: ${result}")
            result = 1
            System.out.println("----- after: ${result}")

        then:
            if (true) {
                assert result == 1
            }
            else {
                [Mock(Closure)].each {
                    it.call() >> ""
                }
            }
    }

    def 'working condition check'() {
        given:
            def result = 0

        when:
            System.out.println("----- before: ${result}")
            result = 1
            System.out.println("----- after: ${result}")

        then:
            if (true) {
                assert result == 1
            }
            if (false) {
                [Mock(Closure)].each {
                    it.call() >> ""
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If you run the above, you would see output that looks something like this:

```
ConditionalCondition > non-working condition check FAILED
    org.spockframework.runtime.SpockComparisonFailure at ConditionalCondition.groovy:15

ConditionalCondition > working condition check STANDARD_OUT
    ----- before: 0
    ----- after: 1
```

As you can see, even the console output doesn't show up, as the code in `then` block never executes. And the report looks like this, again confirming the same fact:

```
  non-working condition check

 Condition not satisfied:

 result == 1
 |      |
 0      false

         at ConditionalCondition.non-working condition check(ConditionalCondition.groovy:15)

Tests

   Test                        Duration Result
   non-working condition check 0.350s   failed
   working condition check     0.030s   passed
```

The only difference between the two tests is the condition around the below code:

```
                [Mock(Closure)].each {
                    it.call() >> ""
                }
```

The code itself does nothing useful to the test, but when the code is the `else` block it doesn't work, but if it is in a separate `if` condition it works fine. Also if I move the code out of the block or remove the code completely, the test works as expected.

Could anyone help me understand this weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to look under the hood of how Spock works it's magic.

To make things like

```
def "mock example"() {
        given:
        Receiver receiver = Mock()
        def producer = new Producer(receiver)
        
        when:
        producer.createItem()
    
        then:
        1 * receiver.receive(_) >> true
    }
```

work, it moves all mock interaction declarations from the `then` block directly in front of the `when` block code.

This is how the code looks after the AST transformation.

```
@org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureMetadata(name = 'mock example', ordinal = 2, line = 43, blocks = [org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.SETUP[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41, org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.WHEN[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41, org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.THEN[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41], parameterNames = [])
    public void $spock_feature_0_2() {
        Receiver receiver = this.MockImpl('receiver', Receiver)
        java.lang.Object producer = new Producer(receiver)
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().enterScope()
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().addInteraction(new org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionBuilder(52, 9, '1 * receiver.receive(_) >> true').setFixedCount(1).addEqualTarget(receiver).addEqualMethodName('receive').setArgListKind(true, false).addEqualArg(_).addConstantResponse(true).build())
        producer.createItem()
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
    }
```

If we take your code, then we can see that the same thing happens.

```
    @org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureMetadata(name = 'non-working condition check', ordinal = 0, line = 5, blocks = [org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.SETUP[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41, org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.WHEN[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41, org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.THEN[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41], parameterNames = [])
    public void $spock_feature_0_0() {
        org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector $spock_errorCollector = org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorRethrower.INSTANCE
        org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder $spock_valueRecorder = new org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder()
        java.lang.Object result = 0
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().enterScope()
        then:
        if (true) {
            try {
                org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), 'result == 1', 16, 24, null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(2), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(0), result) == $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(1), 1)))
            } 
            catch (java.lang.Throwable $spock_condition_throwable) {
                org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, 'result == 1', 16, 24, null, $spock_condition_throwable)} 
            finally { 
            } 
        } else {
            [this.MockImpl(null, null, groovy.lang.Closure)].each({ 
                return this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().addInteraction(new org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionBuilder(20, 21, 'it.call() >> ""').addEqualTarget(it).addEqualMethodName('call').setArgListKind(true, false).addConstantResponse('').build())
            })
        }
        java.lang.System.out.println("----- before: $result")
        result = 1
        java.lang.System.out.println("----- after: $result")
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
    }

    @org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureMetadata(name = 'working condition check', ordinal = 1, line = 25, blocks = [org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.SETUP[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41, org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.WHEN[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41, org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.THEN[]org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@d9f41], parameterNames = [])
    public void $spock_feature_0_1() {
        org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector $spock_errorCollector = org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorRethrower.INSTANCE
        org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder $spock_valueRecorder = new org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder()
        java.lang.Object result = 0
        java.lang.System.out.println("----- before: $result")
        result = 1
        java.lang.System.out.println("----- after: $result")
        then:
        if (true) {
            try {
                org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), 'result == 1', 36, 24, null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(2), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(0), result) == $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(1), 1)))
            } 
            catch (java.lang.Throwable $spock_condition_throwable) {
                org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, 'result == 1', 36, 24, null, $spock_condition_throwable)} 
            finally { 
            } 
        }
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
    }
```

Comment: In your example, the `addInteraction` doesn't cause it to be evaluated immediately right? Let me try to do the same analysis for my sample code and see what happens.

Comment: Looked at the two decompiled methods and understood what is going on in the context of your explanation. The reason the `if`/`else` fails is because Spock moves the entire block ahead of `when` block because it can't move just the `else` block. When the interactions are in a separate if condition, only that block gets moved and so it works. Thanks for helping me understand this, I originally thought it was Spock bug.

Comment: You've stumbled in one of the rare edge cases where Spock magic doesn't do what you want and it is hard to understand why without deeper knowledge of how it works.